# Get call back when frame change

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, frame

I am trying to change the frame of a view with animation. I want to know the frame during the animation. Here is what I am doing:

```
[_viewTemp addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:NULL];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    CGRect frame = _viewTemp.frame;
    frame.origin.x += 100;
    _viewTemp.frame = frame;
}];
```

Here `_viewTemp` is my UIView class object. I want every frame change while animation is working.
Like:
Current origin is {10,10} After the animation complition it will be {110,10}. I want a Callback for every frame change like {11,10}, {12, 10}.

I don't know if this is possible. Using the KVO I am able to get the call back only once. Even by creating subclass and handling the

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame;
```

is not working as expected.

Just want to make sure if this is possible or not and if Yes than how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a timer. In the timer event handler do this

```
-(void)timerHandler:(NSTimer *)timer {

  CGRect frame = [_tempView.layer.presentationLayer frame]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
#define kRight          YES
#define kLeft           NO;

@interface ViewController ()
{
    bool _moveDirection;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _moveDirection = kRight;
}

- (IBAction)actionChange:(id)sender {

    __block NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:-1 target:self selector:@selector(handleAnimationTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

        CGRect frame = self.outletLabel.frame;

        if(_moveDirection == kRight) {
            _moveDirection = kLeft;
            frame.origin.x += 100;
        } else {
            _moveDirection = kRight;
            frame.origin.x -= 100;
        }
        self.outletLabel.frame = frame;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        // Remove timer
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }];

}


-(void)handleAnimationTimer:(NSTimer *)timer{

    CGRect frame = self.outletLabel.frame;
    NSLog(@"frame X %.00f", frame.origin.x);

}
```

You'll be able to see that the *Frame does **not** change **during** the animation* - It's only set at the **beginning** of the animation.

I would suggest you roll your own frame animation (by using the scheduled Timer shown above) and adjust the frame during each call to

```
handleAnimationTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
```